# setting global parameter in rails are not properly working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function like this to set global parameter in a controller of ruby on rails.

```
def set_author
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
end
```

and I set it value by calling before_action

```
before_action :set_author,only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
```

After render the form it will get below error unless I set the @author manually in each function. This is really insane as other controllers work well except this controller after I changed it name.

> NoMethodError at /authors/1/edit undefined method `to_key' for #Author::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005634de007f58 Did you mean? to_set to_ary

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: U means this kinda trace back ?NoMethodError at /authors/1/edit
undefined method `to_key' for #<Author::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005634de007f58>
Did you mean?  to_set
               to_ary

Comment: I mean all the other lines in the log for the request that explain what URL was called and what controller and view methods were called. Because we need for information to be able to help. At the moment we only know that there was `to_key` called on a `Relation`. But the code you posted neither calls `to_key` nor there is a `Relation` created. Therefore we need more information to help you debug the error. The whole request and the full error message with the stack trace from the log file might give us hints what went wrong.

Comment: **Thats not a global.** Its an instance variable that belongs to the controller. Rails "shares" the instance variables of the controller with the view and helpers through the view context so I understand why you would be fooled but globals in Ruby start with the sigil `$`  not `@`.

Comment: @spickermann. I just copy the log in terminal. Is this what u meant ?                NoMethodError - undefined method `to_key' for #<Author::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000564ccdf67cd0>
Did you mean?  to_set
               to_ary:
  app/views/authors/_form.html.erb:1
  app/views/authors/new.html.erb:3

Comment: Dear, max. Yeah but I mean normally in If I call before_action then in new, update and edit function I dont have to set @author value in each function. It is really weird. Unless I create it with scaffold, otherwise it wont work by create controller and model seperately